# Conductors in electric circuits And electrostatics

Tags: electrostatics, batteries

I know from electrostatics that electric field inside a conductor is zero. I also know that there must be electric field inside a conductor carrying current in electric circuits. I am confused.

Comment: Also, for AC there's the [skin effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect), which is especially important at high frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

By Ohm‘s law the current density in a resistive material is proportional to the electric field in it:
$$\mathbf j=\sigma \mathbf E$$ where $\sigma$ is the conductivity. Since all conductors have a non-zero resistance (except for superconductors), there has to be according to Ohm‘s law an electric field in the conductor to make a current flow.

**But why we say sometimes there is no electric field inside a conductor?**

Well, this only applies to the static case when there are no currents flowing. Then the charges will distribute in such a way that there is no electric field inside the conductor (this agrees also with Ohm‘s law).

But in a electric circuit we permanently deliver energy through a voltage source. This leads to an ongoing current flow which requires an electric field inside the conductor.

Comment: We often claim the field is zero in a conductor, because we're condidering the limit as $\sigma$ goes to infinity.

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes, sure. But for the static case it is also zero for a finite $\sigma$. Otherwise a Faraday cage would not work properly.

Answer (score 1):

> I know from electrostatics that electric field inside a conductor is zero. I also know that there must be electric field inside a conductor carrying current in electric circuits.

Like the other answer says, you are correct that there must be a field within the conductor for a current to flow because of Ohm's law

$$\vec{J}=\sigma\vec{E}.$$

However, often $\sigma$ is large enough that $\vec{E}$ can be very small. Small enough to not significantly change the solution to a problem relative to assuming the field is 0.

For example, maybe the conductor is a wire connecting to a 1 kohm resistor, and carrying 1 mA of current. Then the voltage dropped across each resistor is 1 V, but the voltage dropped across the wire may be only a few microvolts. In this case we can approximate that the field in the wire as 0, and the voltage drop across the wire as 0 and still get an acceptably accurate solution to our main problem (how much current flows through the resistor).

Or, maybe the conductor is a metal object being probed by a radar beam. If we assume the field in the conductor is 0, we get a perfect reflection from the object. If we consider the finite conductivity of the metal, there is a small absorption of radiation rather than perfect reflection and a tiny phase change in the reflected wave. But these effects may be irrelevant to the main problem of determining whether our radar can detect the object.